# Design pattern for making a web service respond to a large number of input parameter rules

Tags: java, web-services, spring, servlets

What design pattern is used when a HTTP-based service, which could be called with a number of different parameters, is designed?

Some parameters are required, some are optional, some must be used together, others are completely contradictory. I am tired of doing the same if-this-and-that-do-whatever thing, and clutter my service methods. There must be a better way.

I am familiar with the concept of request filters, but that also helps only partially, because  I have to supply them with the same data context that I supply my controllers with.

What is the appropriate way to generate all the input rules in an decoupled fashion?

Comment: Maybe the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) could help you out here.

Comment: I think this is not really web-service related. It's the same problem in all types of applications - you have complex input validation rules. You can either design (use) a validation component that can be used in different operations or you introduce some kind of rules-engine.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a Designpattern (or at least I don't know that it is one). But what is about a "configuration object".

This configuration object is a more or less stupid bean, like a Data Transfer Object. Which contains all the parameters you need.

The configuration object itself has a method to check if it is valid.

In addition you can make its usage more meaningful. For example if you have to properties that always (and only)  must be used together, then do not have setters for each of them. Instead have a method takes both parameters at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I would externalized this parameters-to-method mapping in some XML file which is loaded by a singleton class that applies rules to the current request and returns method name, for instance.

Just some thoughts:

```
<methods>
    <method name="method1">
        <method-param name="param1"/>
        <method-param name="param2" required="true" validator="<validator class>"/>
        <method-param name="param3" required="true" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
    </method>
    <method name="method2">
        <method-param name="param4" required="true"/>
        <method-param name="param5" required="true"/>
        <method-param name="param6"/>
        <method-param-group required="true" validator="<validator class>">
            <method-param name="param7"/>
            <method-param name="param8"/>
        </method-param-group>
    </method>
</methods>
```

Maybe there're existing frameworks.